# using IN statement in mysql php queries

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys I hope everyone doing well.

I want to know how can I use IN statement in PHP Mysql query,
I have this example inside DB table where the column name is Model

```
Model column in mytable
A901:Y921:L102
```

I want to remove: and use it in PHP SQL queries like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE model IN (A901,Y921,L102)
```

I know it's not possible to call like this it should be `IN ('A901','Y621','L102')`

But how can I convert it to this way? I want to make this call in order to get all the related rows from different tables.

my humble try like this

```
    <?php 
    if($mytable->model)
    $mod = explode(':', $mytable->model);
    foreach($mod as $ac)
    { 
     echo $ac;
    ?>
RESULT: A901 Y921 L102
```

I approach your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mod = explode(':', $mytable->model);
$pp = array_fill(0, count($mod), '?');
$paramPlaceholders = implode(',', $pp);
```

Now we have a string like '?,?,?'. These are parameter placeholders to use in SQL syntax. You can pass your array as the parameter values to a prepared statement:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE model IN ({$paramPlaceholders})";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute($mod);
```

---

Re your comment:

I use PDO, and I recommend it over mysqli. The equivalent code for mysqli would be similar:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE model IN ({$paramPlaceholders})";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($mod)), ...$mod);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I am using mysqli to get the data from DB now I am confusing .

Comment: after several try it seems it's not working.